# make button on the same size blackberry

Tags: blackberry, buttonfield

I  want to have two button in the same size one in the left and the other in the right.
This is my code but I get button have the width more than the other

```java
hManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH|FIELD_VCENTER);
hManager.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 15);

B1= new ButtonField("B1", Field.FIELD_LEFT | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK ) {

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
      return 200;
    }
};

B2= new ButtonField("B2", Field.FIELD_RIGHT | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK ) {

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return 200;
    }
};

hmanager.add(B1);
hmanager.add(B2);
```

Comment: this is because of the text size.

Comment: I fixed the width of button how can be the problem of the text? and the text is very small

Comment: once assign the bitmaps to the bottons.if the same problem repeats then chek with padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like

```
public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return (Display.getwidth()/2)-20 ;               
}
```

in your `ButtonField`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is, For example consider the screen width is 240. But as per your code you gave 200 as width for your first button.So 240-200. Now there is 40 is the remaining screen width. So it wont consider the 200 width given for the 2nd button. So because of not enough width, By default it takes the remaining width(Not your given width). So you have to set the button width based on the screen width. And also in your code Field.Field_Right is not work. In vertical manger only you can set the horizontal property.

Answer (score 0):

don't put absolute values, just portion because blackberry screen is different in a large way

@Bbdev solution is the answer in code